# Calculate $\sqrt{i}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

My book gives the following example on how to solve this:

> $$\sqrt{i} = x+yi \Leftrightarrow \\ i = (x+yi)^2 \Leftrightarrow  \\ \color{blue}{\text{ $\\ i  = x^2-y^2 +2xyi\Leftrightarrow \\ x^2-y^2 = 0\land 2xy = 1$}}$$

Then it puts these expressions in a system and solves it:

$$\begin{cases}
     x^2-y^2 = 0  \\
     y = \frac{1}{2x}\\   \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \\  \begin{cases}
     x^2-(\frac{1}{2x})^2 = 0  \\
     y = \frac{1}{2x}\\   \end{cases}  \Leftrightarrow \\ \begin{cases}
     x^2-\frac{1}{4x^2} = 0  \\
     -\\   \end{cases}  \Leftrightarrow \\ \begin{cases}
     4x^4-1=0 \\
     -\\   \end{cases}  \Leftrightarrow \\ \begin{cases}
     x^4 = \frac{1}{4}  \\
     -\\   \end{cases}  \Leftrightarrow \\ \begin{cases}
     x = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
     y = \frac{1}{-2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\\   \end{cases}  \lor \begin{cases}
     x = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{{2}} \\
     y = \frac{1}{2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\\   \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \\  \begin{cases}
     x = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
     y = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\   \end{cases}  \lor \begin{cases}
     x = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
     y = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\   \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \\$$

> In conclusion:
>
> $\sqrt{i} = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$ and $\sqrt{i} =
>  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$

I don't understand the steps I colored in blue. Could anyone explain to me how one thing results in the other?

Comment: Compare real and imaginary parts of the equation above

Comment: @JohnDoe How do i do that?

Comment: As pointed out in the answer, it is a typo. When given an equation $a+ib=c+id$, you can compare the real and imaginary parts of each side and say they are equal, so $a=c$ and $b=d$. In your example, $a=0,b=1,c=x^2-y^2,d=2xy$

Comment: At what level of mathematics are you working? If you know the form $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ for a general complex number, the answer to your problem becomes **far** easier: it’s just a flick of the wrist to deliver the answer.

Comment: @Lubin I just starting to learn complex numbers.

Comment: Too bad — the suggested way of finding $\sqrt i$ is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write $\sqrt{i}$ as $x+yi$, we usually mean that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers.

So $i=(x^2-y^2)+2xyi$ if and only if $x^2-y^2=0$ and $2xy=1$.

Or we may think like this:

Since $(x^2-y^2)=(1-2xy)i=0$, we have

$$(x^2-y^2)^2=(1-2xy)^2(-1)$$

L.H.S. is non-negative and R.H.S. is non-positive. So this implies that both sides are $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$i=(x^2-y^2)+2xyi$$

Comparing the real part: we have $$0=x^2-y^2$$

Comparing the imaginary part: we have $$2xy=1$$

Comment: Wait where is the typo?

Comment: Correct version is $$i=x^2-y^2+2xyi$$ rather than $$i=x^2-y^2+2xy.$$ The $i$ is missing. I was wondering whether that's the confusing part.

Comment: Alright, fixed it. I''l go through your answer now.

Answer (score 3):

**By applying [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):**

$i=\cos\dfrac{(4n+1)\pi}2+i\sin\dfrac{(4n+1)\pi}2=e^{i(4n+1)\frac{\pi}2}$ where $n$ is any integer.

Therefore. $\sqrt{i}=i^{1/2}=e^{i(4n+1)\frac{\pi}2\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=e^{i(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{4}}=\cos\dfrac{(4n+1)\pi}4+i\sin\dfrac{(4n+1)\pi}4$.

Putting the values of $n$ we get,

$\sqrt{i}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}+i\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}(1+i)$ for, $n=\cdots-4,-2,0,2,4\cdots$;

and,

$\sqrt{i}=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}-i\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}(1+i)$ for, $n=\cdots-5,-3,-1,1,3,5\cdots$

So, in general, $\sqrt i=\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}(1+i)=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}(1+i)$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: This is the only proper answer because all the others revert to Cartesian coordinates to get the answer. Kudos to you. (And you beat me to it!)

Comment: Aren't all the exponentials missing an $i$?

Comment: @CyeWaldman I don't know if this answer is appropriate for OP since they said they are just starting to learn complex numbers, so I would say the other methods are better suited.

Comment: @JohnDoe Well,we could argue the point, but maybe that's not the way complex numbers should be taught. I see altogether too many people trying to solve complex number problems with $x+iy$. If that's the way they are being taught then they are (1) being cheated and (2) being crippled in their future endeavors.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Yes, I do agree with you on that, but I suppose that is an issue with the education system instead. :)

Comment: ohh sorry, yes I've made a mistake ... thanks@JohnDoe. I fixed this.

Comment: thanks sir @CyeWaldman and yes I also agree with you :)